# Dart Element: call function on embedded JS Object

Tags: javascript, dart, method-invocation

In this particular case, it's for SVG.  I can get an SVG Element via a query as follows:

```
Element svgEL = querySelector('svg');
```

If I look at the 'svgEL' object, it contains (in brief):

```
[[javascript view]]: svg
[[class]]: SvgSvgElementImpl
  ...
  getScreenCTM: function()       // I want to call this
  ...
```

I presume I'd instantiate a JsObject on something and then do a callMethod on that, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to make that work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to use the corresponding Dart class `GraphicsElement`,  this has the method `getScreenCTM` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-svg/GraphicsElement-class.html

So cast to this type:

```
GraphicsElement gElem = svgEL as GraphicsElement;
gElem.getScreenCTM();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jonas for the heads-up on the dart:svg library.

It turns out I didn't need it because I'm handling this in an event, and the event target object is the raw js 'g' object (this is on a mouseover).  So, I was able to get what I needed thusly:

```
var jsvg = event.target.ownerSvgElement;

var mtx = jsvg.getScreenCtm();
...
```

And then I can create the point and do the inverse transform and all of that.